# What happens when user deletes own question? Are they flagged or moved to another table?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

I would like to know what happens when questions are deleted. Are they moved to another table (such as QuestionsDeleted), or is a flag just sett on its row?

Comment: All posts are soft deleted.

Answer (score 1):

When a post is deleted, it is ***still there***, but only viewable to people who have the [privilege of seeing deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) or are moderators, and they can vote to "un"delete the post as well if they want to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But more about infrastructure and how it has been designed I should ask here?

Comment: @Luccas seeing several comments and this answer read your question the same, I suggest you edit your question to be more specific